# Nginx not open some POST requests

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need open some web site in my localhost sub domain, for example

> https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=bpms
> as
> http://ieee2.localhost/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=bpms

My NginX is like this :

```
 server {
        listen          80;
        server_name         ieee2.localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                        
            proxy_pass https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/;
        }
   }
```

this open many part of HTML page as I expect, But in the search section (in middle of page) where search result must be shown, It is empty and I see so many error in error.log file.

[image: Current status is shown look at address bar and "We were Unable to find result for"]

I need some Nginx config to have simple and full working proxy or another way that support domain mirroring